# Convert two digit year to four digits

Tags: bash, date

Convert a a two digit year to four digits in bash

I have files in the format: test96abcd.TXT
I am extracting the two digit year:

```
echo "test96abcd.TXT" | cut -c4-5
```

and I was hoping to do something like this:

```
echo "test96abcd.TXT" | cut -c4-5 | date +%Y
```

but it doesn't work, let alone I will have a ...Y2K problem (when it is 00, won't know if it is year 1900 or year 2000) although I can handle manually this exception with an "if 00 use 2000".

But is there a more elegant way to deal with this using t he 'date' command?

Comment: Never mind `00`s - how do you know if the date `XX` should EVER be `20XX` vs `19XX` or something else? if you just want to change every `XX` to `20XX` then you don't need `date` for that. Do your files always have 2 digits and only 2 digits in just 1 location or can you get files like `foo76bar83etc.txt` or `foo1234bar.txt` and if so how should they be handled?

Comment: I do know that my dates are from 1980-today (will not go beyond 2030) and they are consistently named as I described. I can do a long case statement but looking for a more elegant way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat ../tst.sh
#!/bin/env bash

for old; do
    [[ $old =~ ^([^0-9]*)(([0-9]*).*) ]] || continue
    year=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    if (( year > 80 )); then
        cent='19'
    else
        cent='20'
    fi
    new="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${cent}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    mv -- "$old" "$new"
done

$ ls
test00abcd.txt  test17abcd.txt  test96abcd.txt

$ ../tst.sh *

$ ls
test1996abcd.txt  test2000abcd.txt  test2017abcd.txt
```